# cannot upload my program to arduino uno

Tags: upload

I bought new Uno yesterday, i made my programme, and i compile it. it was good compiled. however, when i upload the programme to my Uno, it cannot be uploaded and there was a message like this

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1b 
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

Help me please

Comment: so, did you read the troubleshooting web page?

Comment: Yes of course i did

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure u have selected the right COM port
2. Make sure nothing is connected to the pin 0 and 1 in arduino

This happens because the Arduino IDE could not find Arduino Board Connected to the system.